# Using size of an array list

Tags: java, arrays

When I calling the `size` method of my `ArrayList`, I get the error:

> size has private access in ArrayList.

Any advice on this?

```
ArrayList<String> sAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
int arrayL = sAnswers.size;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` is a `private` variable in `List`. Use `someList.size()`.
`length` is a `public` variable in an `Array`. Use `someArray.length`.

```
ArrayList<String> sAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
int arrayL = sAnswers.size();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no accessible `size` variable in `List`. It's a method

Access it like `sAnswers.size();`